# Can Alice Lie to Bob About the World Consistently Without Bob Noticing?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Say Alice records a section of lake,sea or any body of water from above. At a time T, the recording device gives her a nxm matrix A(T). Each entry of A(T) is an avarage water depth at time T, in a small rectangular piece of the water. (nxm is the resolution of recording). The device produces such a matrix in every $\epsilon$ seconds.

Bob knows the device Alice is using, but does not do the recordings himself. So Bob requests data
from Alice. Is there a triple $(n,m,\epsilon)$ so that Bob can convince himself using physics that he is not being lied to?

Bob and Alice both know a rough bound of $ \lVert A(T+\epsilon)-A(T) \rVert_2$ using physics. So, if Alice sends Bob $A(T+\epsilon)$, so that $\lVert A(T+\epsilon)-A(T) \rVert_2$ is larger than this number, then the inconsistency in data can be detected. If Alice tweaks the real $A(T+\epsilon)$ a little bit, so that $ \lVert A(T+\epsilon)-A(T) \rVert_2$ is still small, then her lie can't be possibly detected.

If Alice wanted to tweak reality in some significant way in far future, she needs to lie little by little.

If there is algorithm and hardware combination in todays technology that can detect, or predict with high accuracy, the self-inconsistency in these data, with doing much less computing then doing simulation? I feel like Bob can convince himself that he is not being lied to if such algorithm exists.

Is this reasoning true? Is there such an algorithm? Is there Laplace's Demon hiding somewhere in this logic? Thanks for reading.

Comment: She can send the actual data shited in time, this would be wrong data but a perfectly plausible one.

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one body of water in the world.  If Alice reports measurements that are accurate for the Pacific on Monday, those measurements will be self-consistent (whether she actually measured the Pacific on Monday or whether she just happened to invent numbers that just happen to accurately describe the Pacific on Monday).   If she reports those numbers as describing the Atlantic on Friday, how could Bob know she's lying?

Answer (score 0):

The Butterfly Effect is relevant here. If the water flow is chaotic like atmospheric flows, she can.

The actual data is a set of $n\times m$ matrices. A slightly different scenario plays out with an indetectably different first matrix, and proceeds from there according to physics. The two scenarios diverge exponentially until they are totally different.

Alice reads the first scenario, but reports the second.